# VPS, VPN and Policy Routing in Linux

Tags: linux, ssh, openvpn, iproute, vps

I am looking for a way to configure my VPN on my VPS in a way that my SSH connection will go through regular network, but all other traffic that goes out of that VPS will go through VPN.

I decided to use policy routing for this.

I've added a new routing table called VPN to /etc/iptables2/rt_tables file

Then I've marked all the packets that are not SSH

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp ! --dport 22 -j MARK --set-mark 1
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING ! -p tcp -j MARK --set-mark 2
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p tcp ! --sport 22 -j MARK --set-mark 3
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT ! -p tcp -j MARK --set-mark 4
```

And assigned them to newly created policy:

```
ip rule add fwmark 1 table VPN
ip rule add fwmark 2 table VPN
ip rule add fwmark 3 table VPN
ip rule add fwmark 4 table VPN
```

now since OpenVPN will by default add all routes to main routing table, I used the --route-noexec to prevent that from happening and created a script that will simply add default route to the VPN routing table using the Environmental variables:

```
openvpn --config [config file] --script-security 2 --route-noexec --route-up /home/user/script.sh
```

And the script itself is just:

```
#cat script.sh

#!/bin/bash
ip route add default via $route_vpn_gateway table VPN
```

After executing this command I am still logged in to the VPS but I have no connection to the outside world.

Here's what I can see in my routing tables:

```
# ip route show table VPN

default via 10.7.7.1 dev tun0

# ip route show table main

default via [VPS Gateway] dev eth0 
10.7.7.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.7.7.210 
[VPS Gateway] dev ens3 scope link
```

Now my understanding is that the second line from the main routing table should not be there, but I'm not sure how to move it to the VPN table.

Any clues? Also - any ideas what else am I missing in this config?

Thank you